# Pipeline production oneHotEncoding

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm trying to automatize my training , predict process.
But i have a problem with one hot encoding .

Let's say i have a column that look like this :

```
column /
a      /
b      /
c      /
```

If i onehot encode it i'll get 3 columns for each letters , but if later after i download some new data , in this same column i have only a and b , the column named "column_c" won't be created and so i cannot predict using the model because of the shape , i'll have 2 columns instead of 3.

How can i fix that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error you describe will only happen if you retrain your OneHotEncoder, which you should not do in an automated process. You should train your OneHotEncoder just like any other ML model once on your training dataset and then apply this trained encoder to whatever new data you want to feed through your automated pipeline.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"cat_col":["a","b","c"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"cat_col":["a","b"]})

ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")

print(ohe.fit_transform(df1).toarray())
print(ohe.transform(df2).toarray())
```

This will return

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```

Comment: I understand , so i should also save it . i saw somewhere that i can pickle it .
Is that the right solution ?

Comment: Is there any other way ?

Comment: This is the standard way. While I guess you could hack your way around it, I don't see what the benefits would be